org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InconsistentTopicIdException in Kafka server
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InconsistentTopicIdException: Tried to assign topic ID Some(XXXX) to log for topic partition -0,but log already contained topic ID YYYYYY

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Delete the topic and try to set the server up again. It should be working.
